# Have two objects animate, one after the other, when scrolled using jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, delay, opacity

I have two objects that I want to fade-in when scrolled past, which works fine using the code below, but what I want is for the first object `.cta-first` to fade-in as it currently does, but then for the second object `.cta-second` to fade-in after the first.

I don't mind if the second object fades-in once the first object is at `opacity: 1`, or after a short time (ie. 1 sec). Both objects are on the same line so will be scrolled to at the same time.

If someone could show me how this can be done using the code below I'd really appreciate it, thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

    $('.cta-first').each(function () {
      var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
      if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
        $(this).animate({
          'opacity': '1'
        }, 2000);
      }
    });

    $('.cta-second').each(function () {
      var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
      if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
        $(this).animate({
          'opacity': '1'
        }, 2000);
      }
    });

  });
});
```

Below is the HTML of the objects targeted.

```
<section class="sidebar">

  <div class="sidebar-module">
    <a href="/contact"><span class="cta-first">This text</span><span class="cta-second">That text</span></a>
  </div>

</section>
```

UPDATE

So I have edited the code suggested by @pdoherty926, which now looks as below. It works fine if I reload the page if the objects are in view - they fadein one after the other, but if I'm at the top of the page when it reloads and scroll down, only `.cta-first` appears, `opacity: 1` is not being applied to the second.

Can anyone see why this is happening? Thanks.

Just to add, the issue is on Chrome and Safari desktop browsers, it's working fine on Safari iOS.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function () {

    var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

    $('.cta-first').each(function () {
      var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
      if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
        $.when($('.cta-first').animate({
          opacity: 1
          }, 2000))
          .then(function () {
            $('.cta-second').animate({
            opacity: 1
          }, 2000);
        });
      }
    });

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's Promise API:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        var bottom_of_object = $('.cta-first').offset().top + $('.cta-first').outerHeight();

        if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {

            // stop and do not complete animations on both elements
            $('.cta-first, .cta-second').stop(true, false);

            $.when($('.cta-first').stop(true, true, false).animate({
              opacity: 1
            }, 2000))
            .then(function () {
                $('.cta-second').animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, 2000);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E6ezn/2/)

Comment: I can see how that might work, though I'm lost on how I would implement that into the code above, as I'm only a js beginner. Thanks.

Comment: I have got your code to work partially (see my update above), if you can see why it's not fully working I would appreciate a reply. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for that, it's almost working right. If the area is in view on reload, it works fine; if I scroll down to it however, it appears that `.cta-first` is already visible, so straight away `.cta-second` fades in. This is on desktop browsers, on iOS it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the callback of the fadeIn() function to start animation on the second object.

Example:

```
  $('.cta-first').each(function () {
      var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
      if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
        $(this).fadeIn(2000, function () {
           //start animating the second item here.
        });
      }
    });
```

The problem is that you are looping through each of the classes, so you would have to restructure the way you are targeting the second object in comparison to the first. Would need to see your html for that.

EDIT: Based on the HTML you posted, can I assume you only have 1 cta-first & 1 cta-second item?

```
    $(document).on('scroll','.sidebar-module', function(){
      var bottom_of_object = $('.cta-first').offset().top + $(.cta-first).outerHeight();
      if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
        $('.cta-first').fadeIn(2000, function () {
           //this gets executed when the first one is complete:
           $('.cta-second').fadeIn(2000, function() {
               //complete event of the second fadeIn in case you want to do something here.
           });
        });
      }
    });
```

Note: I haven't tested this and it was written in a rush :) But it should give you an idea on how to use it.

Comment: Have added the HTML as mentioned - if that helps. I only know basic js so would ideally need the full working code if possible. Thanks.

Comment: I had a quick attempt with it just now but couldn't get it to work, but I'll have another look in the morning. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I tried fiddling around with the code but just couldn't seem to get it to work. Thanks for trying to help.